# Testing an expression whether it is always negative given conditions

Tags: expression-test

Suppose we have the following:

$$i(\gamma+\nu)[R s -1]$$

where $i, \gamma, \nu, s > 0$ and $R\leq1$ can we show/test that this will always be negative?

Comment: R=1, s=2 as a counter example. Basically Rs>1 will work as a counter example. If you want the product be always negative, you need Rs<1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = i*(γ + ν)*(R*s - 1);

Assuming[{i > 0, γ > 0, ν > 0, s > 0, R <= 1},
 Simplify[expr < 0]]

(* R s < 1 *)
```

Since this simplifies to a condition rather than `True`, it is not always negative. For example,

```
counterExamples = 
 FindInstance[{expr > 0, i > 0, γ > 0, ν > 0, s > 0, 
   R <= 1}, {i, γ, ν, s, R}, 3]

(* {{i -> 275, γ -> 58, ν -> 70, s -> 68, 
  R -> 87/103}, {i -> 17, γ -> 32, ν -> 10, s -> 7, 
  R -> 1}, {i -> 113, γ -> 12, ν -> 63, s -> 69, R -> 45/103}} *)
```

Verifying that these values make the expression positive

```
expr /. counterExamples

(* {204617600/103, 4284, 25441950/103} *)
```

Comment: What about if we add the condition $s+i \leq1$

Comment: `Assuming[{i > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Nu] > 0, s > 0, R <= 1, s + i <= 1}, 
 Simplify[expr < 0]]` evaluates to `True` and `counterExamples = 
 FindInstance[{expr >= 0, i > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Nu] > 0, s > 0, 
   R <= 1, s + i <= 1}, {i, \[Gamma], \[Nu], s, R}]` returns an empty list. Both indicate that under the given constraints that the expression is always negative.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = i*(γ + ν)*(R*s - 1);
ForAll[{i, R, s, γ, ν}, 
  And @@ {i > 0, γ > 0, ν > 0, s > 0, R <= 1}, expr >= 0];
Resolve[%]
```

> `False`

Comment: what about if we add the condition $s+i\leq1$? when I tried, it gave me a "true" output confirming it is always negative?